# How to get SQL Server Name Using Windows Authetication in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to fetch the Server Name using C# for that I am trying blow mentioned code.

```
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader dr;

 con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Database=Master;Integrated Security=SSPI");
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select *  from sysservers  where srvproduct='SQL Server'", con);

                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {

                    ServerCollection.Add(dr[2].ToString());

                }

                dr.Close();
```

it's give me Exception like Login faild for user Dhaval.patel so can anyone please help how to connect using window's Authetication in C#.

Comment: What is the exception _exactly_? On which line?

Comment: on con.Open exception Login failed for user 'PLAYROOM\dhaval.patel'. InnerException null

Comment: Why you have defined `Data source = .` two times in connection string ?

Comment: I have chananged it still it's not working

Comment: Check if the server authentication mode is not set only to SQL Server Authentication.

Comment: @Bayeni: yes I have changed the authentication mode to Windows then it's working in my application but when I tried to Connnect it from Management Studio then it's not able to connect niether Window nor SQL Authetication

Comment: Restart the SQL server and if you have SQL server agent running, you must restart it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Put `Integrated Security  = true` like this

```
con =  new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Database=Master; Integrated Security=true");
```

Comment: what is your sqlserver instance name ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be like :-

```
 ("Server= localhost; Database=Master;Integrated Security=SSPI, Integrated Security=True");
```

If you have a named instance of SQL Server, you'll need to add that as well, 
e.g.,

```
"Server=localhost\sqlexpress"
```

Comment: yes if I used the  con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Database=Master;data source=.; uid=" + UserName + "; pwd=" + Password + ";"); then it's working fine

Comment: using SQL Authetication it's working fine but I want to open using Windows Authetication without any username and password

Comment: see this if kai help male to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647396.aspx @DhavalPatel